# Krull dimension of three modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with non-zero identity and $M$, $M'$ and $M''$ be $R$-modules (not necessarily finitely generated) with $\operatorname{Supp} M \subseteq‎ \operatorname{Supp} M'‎\cup‎ \operatorname{Supp} M''$. Is it true that $\dim M ‎\leq‎ \max\{\dim M' , \dim M''\}$?

The Krull dimension of a module $M$ is the supremum of the non-negative integers $n$ such that there exists a chain of prime ideals in $\operatorname{Supp}M$ of length $n$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in my first answer I assumed that all modules are finitely generated, which was not the intention of OP (who actually haven't put his question into precise form at that moment), I decided to edit my answer so that it also covers the general case.

Suppose that dimension of a module $M$ is the supremum of lengths of all chains of prime ideals contained in $\mathrm{supp}(M)$. Note that this definition agrees with the usual one in the case when module is finitely generated. Then the inequality in question holds. This is due to the following **fact**:

> Let $M$ be a module over any commutative unital ring $R$. If $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{supp}(M)$, then $\mathfrak{q}\in \mathrm{supp}(M)$
>   for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$.

**proof:** We have:
$$M_{\mathfrak{q}}\otimes_{R_{\mathfrak{q}}}R_{\mathfrak{p}}=M_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$
Now if $M_{\mathfrak{p}}\neq 0$, then also $M_{\mathfrak{q}}\neq 0$.

Now let $\mathrm{supp}(M)\subseteq \mathrm{supp}(M')\cup \mathrm{supp}(M'')$. Consider a chain:
$$\mathfrak{p}_0\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_1\subseteq \cdots\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_n$$
of prime ideals in $\mathrm{supp}(M)$. Then we have either $\mathfrak{p}_0\in \mathrm{supp}(M')$ or $\mathfrak{p}_0\in \mathrm{supp}(M'')$ and thus by the **fact**, we derive that the whole chain is contained either in $\mathrm{supp}(M'')$ or in $\mathrm{supp}(M'')$. Hence:
$$n\leq \max\{\mathrm{dim}(M'),\mathrm{dim}(M'')\}.$$