# Krull Dimension equality.

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative Noetherian local ring, $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module and $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Supp}_R(M)$. Then I am little confused with the following equality between Krull dimensions: 
\begin{equation}
\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M=\dim_{R/\mathfrak{p}} M/\mathfrak{p}M.\end{equation}

If the above equality holds, then have the following two possibilities:

(1) $\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M=\dim_{R/\mathfrak{p}} M/\mathfrak{p}M\leq \dim_{R/\mathfrak{p}} R/\mathfrak{p}=\dim_R R/\mathfrak{p}$.

(2) As $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Supp}_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)=\mathrm{Supp}_R(M)\cap V(\mathfrak{p})$, it follows that
$\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M\geq \dim_R R/\mathfrak{p}$, which is a contradiction of above statement (1).

Can anyone guide me where am I wrong? I think my first equation is not true. But I do not have any example or argument.

Comment: I think (2) is not wrong. Since $\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M$ can be computed as
$
\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M=\sup\{\dim R/\mathfrak{q}: \mathfrak{q}\in Supp_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)\}
$
Moreovoer, it is easy to see that $Supp_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)=Supp_R(M)\cap V(\mathfrak{p})$

Comment: Yes, you are right. but following argument confuses me.

Since $\mathfrak{p}, \in Supp_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)$, then by definition of $\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M$, we have

$\dim_{R} (M/\mathfrak{p}M)=\sup\{\dim_R{R/\mathfrak{q}} : \mathfrak{q}\in Supp_{R} (M/\mathfrak{p}M)\}\geq \dim_{R} (R/\mathfrak{p})$.

Please, tell me the mistake in my understanding.

Comment: Suppose that $\dim_R R/\mathfrak{p}=r$, then there exists a chain of prime ideals

$
\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_0\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_1\subseteq \dots\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_r
$

It follows that $\mathfrak{p}_i\in Supp_R(M)\cap V(\mathfrak{p})=Supp_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)$. Hence, by definition of $\dim_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)$, we have

$
\dim_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)\geq r=\dim_R R/\mathfrak{p}.
$

This proves my claim. Please tell me the mistake in above proof.

Comment: Let $M$ be a module over any commutative unital ring $R$. If $p\in Supp_R(M)$, then $q\in Supp_R(M)$ for every prime ideal $q$ containing $p$. Answer of this question was given by you. See the link below:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829795/krull-dimension-of-three-modules?rq=1

Comment: Well, I missed that you assumed $\mathfrak p\in\mathrm{Supp}(M)$. In this case $\mathrm{Supp}(M/\mathfrak pM)=V(\mathfrak p)$, and therefore $\dim_R M/\mathfrak{p}M=\dim_{R/\mathfrak{p}} M/\mathfrak{p}M=\dim_RR/\mathfrak p=\dim R/\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Thanks, it was a nice discussion with you.